# Timer control in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I'm trying to set one boolean false after 2 seconds(showSpinner) but can't handle it, main idea is showing loading spinner for 2 seconds after than showing solution but spinner never stops and solution never shows up(spinner is loading spinner, text = solution) [image]

```
@override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    showSpinner=true;

      Timer(Duration(seconds: 2),(){
        setState(() {
          showSpinner=false;
        });
      });

  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {


     Widget child;
      if (showSpinner == true && isPressed4 == true) {
        setState(() {
          Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
            showSpinner == false;
          });
        });

        child = spinkit;
      }

      if (showSpinner == false && isPressed4 == true) {
        text = simpleInterest.accumulationFunction(
            time, yearlySimpleInterestRate, principal);
        child = Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        );
      }
```

there are 3 buttons(isPressed1 for button 1 and isPressed2 for button2 and isPressd3 for button 3, if all true isPressed4 becomes true)

```
 var floatingActionButton1 = FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              isPressed1 = !isPressed1;
            });
            setState(() {
              principal = double.parse(_principalController.text);
            });
            setState(() {
              if (isPressed3 == true && isPressed2 == true && isPressed1 == true) {
                isPressed4 = true;
              }
            });
          },
          elevation: 40,
          backgroundColor: isPressed1 ? Colors.lightGreenAccent : null,
          heroTag: "btn1",
          child: Icon(Icons.check),
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is `spinkit` and `isPressed4`, but I would do it like this:

```
  bool showSpinner;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showSpinner = true;

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        showSpinner = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Title'),
        ),
        body: buildBody()
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody(){
    return showSpinner ?
    CircularProgressIndicator() :
    Text(
      'The answer',
    );
  }
```

**UPD:**

Initially I have 2 seconds. Then:

- If `showSpinner == false` and `floatingActionButton1` has not been pressed, then I get text `The time is up!`.
- If `showSpinner == true` and `floatingActionButton1` has not been pressed, then I get text `Button 4 is not pressed yet`.
- If `showSpinner == true` and `floatingActionButton1` has been pressed, then I get `CircularProgressIndicator()`(as in the question).
- If `showSpinner == false` and `floatingActionButton1` has been pressed, then I get `Text` with `The answer`(as in the question):

```
  bool showSpinner;

  var floatingActionButton1;

  bool isPressed1;
  bool isPressed2;
  bool isPressed3;
  bool isPressed4;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showSpinner = true;

    isPressed1 = false;
    isPressed2 = true;
    isPressed3 = true;
    isPressed4 = false;

    floatingActionButton1 = FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          isPressed1 = !isPressed1;

          if (isPressed3 == true && isPressed2 == true && isPressed1 == true) {
            isPressed4 = true;
          }
        });
      },
      backgroundColor: isPressed1 ? Colors.lightGreenAccent : null,
      child: Icon(Icons.check),
    );

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        showSpinner = false;
      });
    });
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child;

    if(showSpinner == false && isPressed4 == false)
      child = Text('The time is up!');

    else if(showSpinner == true && isPressed4 == false)
      child = Text('Button 4 is not pressed yet');

    else if (showSpinner == true && isPressed4 == true) {
      child = CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

    else if (showSpinner == false && isPressed4 == true) {
      child = Text(
        'The answer',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Title'),
        ),
        body: child,
      floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton1,
    );
  }
```

Comment: and should i add if statement in initState ( for check if isPressed4 = true )

Comment: @EmirKutlugün can you clarify what exactly `isPressed4` is and what you want from it?

Comment: i have 3 inputs, isPressed4 is checking if these inputs are given by the user, i can put design of my page if you want

Comment: @EmirKutlugün yes, please share your full code of this page

Comment: whole code is like 260 lines so i can't add all of them, but main principle is simple user will write inputs and check boxes, if all boxes are checked, isPressed4 will be true, if isPressed4 becomes true, the loading widget and solution widget will work, but problem is after 2 seconds loading widget, don't stop working i mean i' cant make showSpinner boolean false after 2 seconds.

Comment: @EmirKutlugün ok, then look at my timer initialization, it fixes two of your problems: 1. You check is `showSpinner == false`, but my function set `showSpinner` to false: `showSpinner = false`, 2. you need to use `setState()` inside the `Timer` callback, not outside. Is this solves your problem?

Comment: @EmirKutlugün have you also removed `setState()` and `Timer` from `build()`? I tested my code from answer and it works as intended. If this doesn't work, please separate your working code from problem code and post the full problem code in your question.

Comment: @EmirKutlugün please also post `isPressed4`(or remove it) and the rest of your `build()` function

Comment: @EmirKutlugün please, check my updated answer. I also added the specification of this tested code(actual behavior of this code). As I said, I can fix only that code that I see, so this code works correctly(according to the described specification). Did it help you? If not, please separate working code from not working code or post all related code.

Comment: didn't saw your answer and solved it with another way but thanks a lot i've learned much with your answers

Answer (score 0):

```
void startTimer() {
      const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
      _timer = new Timer.periodic(
        oneSec,
        (Timer timer) => setState(
          () {
            if (_start ==0) {
              showSpinner=false;
              timer.cancel();
            } else {
              _start = _start - 1;
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _timer.cancel();
      super.dispose();
    }
```

solved with making this function and modifying buttons like;

```
var floatingActionButton1 = FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              isPressed1 = !isPressed1;
            });
            setState(() {
              principal = double.parse(_principalController.text);
            });
            setState(() {
              if (isPressed3 == true && isPressed2 == true && isPressed1 == true) {
                isPressed4 = true;
                startTimer();
              }
            });
          },
          elevation: 40,
          backgroundColor: isPressed1 ? Colors.lightGreenAccent : null,
          heroTag: "btn1",
          child: Icon(Icons.check),
        );
```